# Relax Egoroff's Theorem to pointwise convergence a.e. and bounded a.e. pointwise limit

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

The following question is taken from Royden's Real Analysis $4$th edition, Chapter $3,$ question $28,$ page $67:$

> **Question:** Show that Egoroff's Theorem continues to hold if the convergence is pointwise a.e. and $f$ is finite a.e., that is.
>
> Assume $E$ has finite measure. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $E$ that converges pointwise almost everywhere on $E$ to the real-valued function $f$ which is finite almost everywhere. Then for each $\varepsilon>0,$ there is a closed set $F$ contained in $E$ for which 
>   $$\{f_n\}\to f \text{ uniformly on }F \text{ and }m(E\setminus F)<\varepsilon.$$

My attempt:

Let $A = \{ x\in E: f_n\not\to f \text{ pointwise} \}$ and $B=\{ x\in E: |f|=\infty \}.$ 
By assumption, 
$$m(A)=m(B)=0.$$
So $A$ and $B$ are measurable. 
Note that 
$$m[E\setminus (A\cup B)] = m(E) - m(A\cup B) = m(E).$$
Fix $\varepsilon>0.$
Since $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $E\setminus (A\cup B)$ to the real-valued function $f,$ by Egoroff's Theorem, there exists a closed set $F$ contained in $(E\setminus (A\cup B))\subseteq E$ for which 
$$f_n\to f \text{ uniformly on } F \text{ and }m[(E\setminus(A\cup B)) \setminus F] < \varepsilon.$$
Since $E$ has finite measure and $F\subseteq E,$ by monotonicity,  $F$ has finite measure.
As $F$ is closed, it is also measurable. 
Therefore, by Excision property, we have
$$m(E\setminus F) = m(E) - m(F) = m[E\setminus(A\cup B)] - m(F) = m[(E\setminus(A\cup B)) \setminus F]<\varepsilon.$$

Is my proof correct? I ask for verification because in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166351/egoroffs-theorem-continues-to-hold-if-the-convergence-is-point-wise-a-e-and-f?rq=1) Kenny's comment about countable union of null sets. I do not use this anywhere in my proof. So I wonder whether my proof miss out something.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand which part of the linked document you are referring to. Maybe I missed something, but I didn’t see anything about Egoroff’s theorem in there.

Comment: What's up with the title?  The title seems to suggest that you want to prove a version of Egoroff on a domain with infinite measure, but in the body of your question, only finite-measure domains are considered.

Comment: But in your proof you assume that $m(E) < \infty$!  And you'll have to clarify what it is that you want to prove, because the obvious statement for Egoroff on an infinite-measure domain is plainly false and there are easy counterexamples.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I apologize for mixing up between Egoroff's Theorem and Lusin's Theorem. For this post, I want to prove that Egoroff's Theorem holds for almost everywhere pointwise convergence and $f$ is finite almost everywhere.

Comment: But the boxed Question combined with the statement of "Egoroff's theorem" below seems to clearly be about finite-measure domains.  Would you please reread the title and body of your question, and then give a complete and precise statement of what you want to prove.  Please don't say "I want to prove Egoroff's theorem for foo foo foo" but instead write it out: "I want to prove that if $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere and blah blah blah then there is a set $F$ such that yah yah yah."  And state explicitly what you assume about the domain.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the post.

Comment: Egoroff's theorem requires that $\{f_n\}$ be measurable on its domain. How do you know that $\{f_n\}$ is measurable on $E\backslash (A\cup B)$?

Answer (score 2):

The proof looks fine. Kenny's cited comment ("Can't you remove from $E$ the subsets on which $f_n$ doesn't converge pointwise and the subset on which the limit is not finite? A countable union of null sets is null") does not really need to mention countable unions, since all you need here is a finite union of (two) null sets.